# How to solve k-means value error in python?

Tags: python, pandas, cluster-analysis, k-means, valueerror

i have a dataframe with mixed data. The data includes different categories, like location, employee ID, job code, and some other values. I converted to indicator variables:

`data_norm = pd.get_dummies(data)`
then, my dataset looks like 4414 rows × 12995 columns
then tried using a basic implementation of k-means:

```
kmeans = KMeans(6)
clusters = kmeans.fit_predict(data_norm_df)
labels = pd.DataFrame(clusters)
labeleddata = pd.concat((data,labels),axis=1)
labeleddata = labeleddata.rename({0:'labels'},axis=1)
```

but get this error: `ValueError: n_samples=1 should be >= n_clusters=6.`

i also tried this:

```
k_means = KMeans(n_clusters=3, random_state=0)
k_means.fit(data_norm_df)
clusters = k_means.fit_predict(data_norm_df)
labels = pd.DataFrame(clusters)
labeleddata = pd.concat((data,labels),axis=1)
labeleddata = labeleddata.rename({0:'labels'},axis=1)
```

I am not sure why it assumes there is only one sample as my dataset has 4414 rows. Please help!

Comment: This questions needs a bit more information. For example, what the data looks like, the structure of the dataframe would be helpful. Clearly the input of the kmeans method is wrong, so debugging that would be the key